# Detecting claps vs blowing into mic

Tags: swift

Is there a way to detect blowing into a mic vs clapping for iOS?  I remember watching a Ted talk of a book and they had a windmill animation when you would blow into the mic.  I have my audioRecorder setup to read the levels of peakPower and I just have it doing an action if it's above -2 db

```
    readLevels()
    let avgPower = audioRecorder?.averagePowerForChannel(0)
    let peakPower = audioRecorder?.peakPowerForChannel(0)
    
    if peakPower >= -2 {
        soundLogicDelegate?.clapDetected()
    }
```

So on loud sounds it does a good enough job for my needs to detect a clap vs talking.  But if blow into the mic, it's kind of the same effect since it's just reading the power levels.  Is there a way to differentiate between clapping vs blowing?